# How to Join the subquery using JSON document within MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

The Mysql version is `8.0.18-commercial`. The primary key of the table is `id`.
I have written the following query which displays `hostname` and `details` columns

```
select hostname, details from table t1;

hostname: abc123
details:
[
  {
    "Msg": "Job Running",
    "currentTask": "IN_PROGRESS",
    "activityDate": "2020-07-20 16:25:15"
  },
  {
    "Msg": "Job failed",
    "currentTask": "IN_PROGRESS",
    "activityDate": "2020-07-20 16:35:24"
  }
]
```

I want the `Msg` value only from the element having most recent `activityDate`

My desired output is displaying `hostname` alongwith `Msg` of the element with `latest date` :

```
hostname        Msg
abc123          Job failed
```

I have written following query and it is running successfully but not displaying anything at all. Morever, it is taking `17secs` to execute.

```
select hostname,
(select Msg
from (
    select x.*, row_number() over(partition by t.id order by x.activityDate) rn
    from table1 t
    cross join json_table(
        t.audits,
        '$[*]' columns(
            Msg varchar(50) path '$.Msg',
            activityDate datetime path '$.activityDate'
        )
    ) x
) t
where rn = 1) AS Msg
from table1;
```

Comment: I appreciate any help with the updated query. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to fix the JSON's format by removing the commas at the end
  of the lines starting with `"activityDate"` keys
- A conversion function such as `STR_TO_DATE()` should be applied to
  the derived `activityDate` columns in order to get date ordered(not
  *characterwise*) results.
- A subquery is not needed through putting `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic
  function next to the `ORDER BY` Clause( *with* **descending** *order* ), and adding a `LIMIT 1` Clause
  at the end of the query

So, you can rewrite the query as

```
SELECT t1.hostname,
       j.Msg
  FROM t1
 CROSS JOIN
     JSON_TABLE(details, '$[*]' 
       COLUMNS (

                Msg VARCHAR(100)  PATH '$.Msg',
                activityDate VARCHAR(100)  PATH '$.activityDate'                        
               )
     ) j 
 ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER ( -- PARTITION BY id 
                ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(j.activityDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S') DESC)    
 LIMIT 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f65d114b8701b70a2857c2da96fd2a48)</kbd>

**Update** :

For the case of having several id values, you may consider using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function within a subquery and filter out the values returning equal to 1 in the main query :

```
SELECT id, Msg
  FROM
  (
   SELECT t1.*, j.Msg,
          ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(j.activityDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S') DESC) AS rn   
     FROM t1
    CROSS JOIN
          JSON_TABLE(details, '$[*]' 
          COLUMNS (    
                   Msg VARCHAR(100)  PATH '$.Msg',
                   activityDate VARCHAR(100)  PATH '$.activityDate'                        
                  )
     ) j 
   ) q
 WHERE rn= 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=792a3f08dc915b14937d5aab220b4587)</kbd>

One another method uses `ROW_NUMBER()` function together with `LIMIT` clause contains Correlated Subquery, and works for records with multiple **id** values :

```
SELECT t.id, 
 ( SELECT j.Msg
     FROM t1
    CROSS JOIN
        JSON_TABLE(details, '$[*]' 
        COLUMNS (
                Msg VARCHAR(100)  PATH '$.Msg',
                activityDate VARCHAR(100)  PATH '$.activityDate'                        
                )
        ) j
     WHERE t1.id = t.id  
     ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() 
              OVER (ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(j.activityDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S') DESC)    
     LIMIT 1 ) AS Msg
  FROM t1 AS t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=103b790fe63627c2f8441c28b36075b3)</kbd>

Comment: I have fixed the JSON and removed commas at the end of `activityDate`

Comment: It is only returning one row. There should be quite a few `hostNames` and corresponding `Msg` values. Do you think I should remove `Limit 1` from the query??

Comment: sure @meallhour for multiple id values, taking ROW_NUMBER() function into a subquery would be a better approach.

Comment: When I remove `Limit 1`, I get multiple entries for the same `hostName`. Let me try running the updated query that you have provided which takes ROW_NUMBER() function into a subquery

Comment: the updated query is not returning any rows. It is executing without any error and giving message as `OK`. It is taking `13secs` to run whereas the previous query is only taking `1sec`. Is there a way you can update the first query so that it doesnt provide duplicate entries for the `hostName`?

Comment: But I don't know about you data set @meallhour . If you only need to get hostname column values distinctly, then convert `SELECT id, hostname, Msg` to `SELECT DISTINCT hostname`, or `SELECT DISTINCT id, hostname`. Depends on what you exactly need.

Comment: The data set is all given here. It is actually displaying all values for `Msg` and `activityDate`. However, we only need `Msg` corresponding to most recent `activityDate`. How can we do `DESC` on `activityDate` and then `Limit 1` on the first query such that all `hostName` values are displayed?

Comment: well, do you want to return *each* **Msg** corresponding to most recent **activityDate** for each (partitioned) **id** value ..?

Comment: Yeah and as a matter of fact there will always be one `Msg` corresponding to any `activityDate`. I just need the `Msg` corresponding to most recent `activityDate` for each (partitioned) `id` value. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Then, just remove id, hostname from the SELECT list, but at least there should remain id in the SELECT list in order to distinguish the records @meallhour . For the case having multiple case, we can consider using a correlated subquery with LIMIT clause as an alternative way. But I think this current method is better to be more straightforward. Case with [correlated subquery](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=103b790fe63627c2f8441c28b36075b3) which I don't prefer.

Comment: I need `hostname`, `id` and it is displaying correct data except that it is displaying `Msg` for all `activityDate` for a particular `id`.  How about if I include `Limit 1` within the brackets?                                           `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY j.activityDate DESC LIMIT 1)`

Comment: No, you can't do this @meallhour

Comment: thanks for all your help. the `correlated subquery` is working fine and executing in less than `1s`. You may update your answer as well. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm old school, but the date field should be stored as a separate field either in additional to the JSON, to allow for easy queries.

Is the ID auto increment, and is the data inserted in timestamp order?  If yes, then you can run a query like this to give you the last row for each hostname:

```
SELECT id, hostname, details 
FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.hostname = t1.hostname AND t2.id > t1.id) ;
```